# Необходима помощь с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Занимаюсь парсингом, и мне необходимы выдернуть данные, которые находятся в Javascript.
Неохота ради одного значения парсить Selenium-ом

Имеется кусок Javascript - кода

```
],
            "data": [["как продать авто без снятия учета",6,33,225,1],["как продать битое авто без снятия с учета",8,41,7,0],["как продать свой авто без снятия с учета",8,40,225,0],["как продать авто без снятия с учета 2017",8,40,8,1],["я продаю авто как мне продать без снятия с учета",10,48,206,0],["как правильно продать авто без снятия с учета",8,45,1,1],["как можно продать авто без снятия учета",7,39,43,0],["как продать битый авто без снятия с учета",8,41,3,3],["как продать авто без снятия с учета минск",8,41,3,1],["как продать авто по договору купли продажи без снятия с учета",11,61,153,11],["как продать авто без снятия с учете",7,35,225,0],["авто без снятия с учета как продать",7,35,264,6],["как продать авто по генеральной доверенности без снятия с учета",10,63,3,3],["как продать авто по договору без снятия с учета",9,47,153,0],["как можно продать авто без снятия с учета",8,41,29,1],["как продать авто без снятия с учета",7,35,226,10],["как продать авто без снятия с учета с номерами",9,46,6,0],["купил авто по договору купли продажи без снятия с учета как продать",12,67,6,0],["как продать авто с номерами без снятия с учета",9,46,6,0],["как продать авто без снятия с учета 2014",8,40,4,0],["как купить продать авто без снятия с учета",8,42,4,0],["как продать авто без снятия с учета 2016",8,40,4,0],["как продать авто в своем регионе без снятия с учета",10,51,3,0],["как продать авто по новым правилам без снятия с учета",10,53,2,0],["как продать авто по договору купли продажи без снятия с учета 2016",12,66,2,0],["как продать авто в другой регион без снятия с учета",10,51,1,0],["как продать авто без снятия с учета в другой регион",10,51,1,0]]

   } );
```

Гарантируется, что на сайте встречается "data" (не data, а именно "data") один раз в javascript

Поэтому я подумал, что возможно дернуть данные из результатов запроса, ограниченные слева `"data"` а справа первые встречающиеся закрывающиеся скобками `]]`

Пытаюсь найти как-то так:

```
^"data":*$]],
```

но думаю не правильно составил

Язык python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
"data":.*\]\]
```